# Buscar string em mais de uma tabela SQL

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Gostaria de buscar uma determinada string usando `LIKE` em mais de 1 tabela. Segue um exemplo de como eu fiz, que provavelmente vai gastar muito tempo ou não irá buscar em todas as tabelas:

```
string SQL1 = @"SELECT *
    FROM TB_1
    WHERE NOME LIKE '%' + @PRODUTO + '%'";

DataAccess db1 = new DataAccess(SQL1);

db1.addParametro("@PRODUTO", SqlDbType.VarChar, produto);

if (db1.GetDataTable().Rows.Count > 0)
{
    return db1.GetDataTable();
}
else
{
    string SQL2 = @"SELECT *
    FROM TB_2
    ....
}
```

Existe uma maneira melhor ou mais fácil?

Answer (score 7):

Utilizar o cláusula UNION é o melhor caminho, veja um exemplo:

Digamos que existem duas tabelas conceituais: TB_CLIENTES e TB_VENDAS.

```
TB_CLIENTES(
    ID,
    NOME,
    ENDERECO_RESIDENCIA,
    CIDADE_RESIDENCIA
)

TB_VENDAS(
    ID,
    CLIENTE_ID,
    VALOR,
    PRODUTO,
    ENDERECO_ENTREGA,
    CIDADE_ENTREGA
)
```

Com os seguintes registros:

```
TB_CLIENTES
  ID    NOME      ENDERECO_RESIDENCIA      CIDADE_RESIDENCIA
  1     "José"    "R. 13 de Maio"          "Monte A. do Sul"
  2     "Maria"   "R. 23 de Maio"          "Serra Negra"
  3     "João"    "R. 7 de Setembro"       "Amparo"

TB_VENDAS
  ID    CLIENTE_ID    VALOR    PRODUTO    ENDERECO_ENTREGA    CIDADE_ENTREGA
  1     3             36.0     "Xícara"     "R. 9 de Abril"       "Pedreira"
  2     2             45.0     "Baú"        "R. 23 de Mario"      "Serra Negra"
  3     1             12.0     "Licor"      "R. João XXIII"       "Amparo"
  4     3             55.0     "Panela"     "R. Maria III"        "Serra"
```

Existe a necessidade de selecionar todos os clientes e/ou compras que a cidade contenha  "Serra" em seu nome.

```
SELECT "CLIENTE" as TIPO, ID, CIDADE_RESIDENCIA as CIDADE, NOME as DISC
FROM TB_CLIENTES
WHERE CIDADE LIKE '%' + @NOME_CIDADE+ '%'

UNION

SELECT "VENDA" as TIPO, ID, CIDADE_ENTREGA as CIDADE, PRODUTO as DISC
FROM TB_VENDAS
WHERE CIDADE LIKE '%' + @NOME_CIDADE+ '%'
```

Como resultado teríamos:

```
TIPO      ID    CIDADE         DISC
"CLIENTE" 2     "Serra Negra"  "Maria"
"VENDA"   2     "Serra Negra"  "Baú"
"VENDA"   4     "Serra"        "Panela"
```

Note que é necessário montar os selects de modo que os tipos de dados e nomes de colunas se tornem comuns entre eles, somente assim você terá sucesso.
E caso os tipos não sejam os mesmos ou as precisões numéricas sejam diferentes você pode utilizar os comandos para cast, que cada SGDB fornece.

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar a cláusula UNION

Verifique a sintaxe do seu banco de dados, no uso do UNION

```
SELECT *
    FROM TB_1
    WHERE NOME LIKE '%' + @PRODUTO + '%'

UNION 
SELECT *
    FROM TB_2
    WHERE NOME LIKE '%' + @PRODUTO + '%'"
```

Comment: O nome das colunas precisam ser os mesmos, se caso tiver uma tabela A uma coluna com nome 'string1' e em outra B 'string2' use um alias na tabela B string2 as string1

Comment: boa, e se uma tabela tiver mais colunas que outra? o problema é esse agora, da um erro falando que devem ter o mesmo numero colunas

Comment: Monte o SELECT de forma que fique com o mesmo numero de colunas. 
Vamos supor que a Coluna email exista apenas na Segunda tabela, e nao na primeira, então
Na primeira tabela fica SELECT Nome, Endereco, NULL AS email

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente é melhor usar algo como Full Text Search (no caso do SQL Server) ou uma ferramente de busca, como o Lucene.

O Full Text Search é uma engine do próprio SQL Server. Específica pra busca em textos, você escolhe as tabelas e colunas e ele cria um índice invertido. É possível fazer diversos tipos de buscar. Como palavras perto uma da outra, sinônimos etc

Mais infos http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

O Lucene já é uma biblioteca externa. Vai gravar os dados em arquivos físicos. É referência no mercado e se não me engano o Stackoverflow agora usa ela.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/

Comment: Seria interessante elaborar um pouco mais a sua resposta. Como usar o Full Text Search, o Lucence, etc.

Comment: Adicionei mais infos. Mas como usar em si já está fora do escopo do site